# CODA live preview for different URL

Tags: php, wordpress, editor, coda

Consider this situation: You are editing template file from some wordpress theme and want to have it in CODAs live preview. As the paths is different it will doens't show live preview.

e.g I'm editing; /wp-content/themes/pixel/header.php
and want to have www.wordpress.loc  in live preview window (I use "loc" for local development )
it only works if I have http://www.wordpress.loc/wp-content/themes/pixel/header.php in live preview. But of course this is unusable for wordpress developer.

Now I have to always click on refresh button in live preview window. Is there any plugin or method how can I do that automatically ?
Please do not suggest me XRefresh or LiveReload as these don't work for internal CODA preview.

Answer (score 4):

In coda version 2 and above you can open a new preview window by clicking 'preview' then clicking 'preview in new window' at the bottom left of the preview screen. 
You can then change the page that is being shown in the url bar of that window to whatever url you want to view in your mamp or whatever.

Now when you save your scripts the preview will refresh and show your changes immediately.

Bit late but it may help someone :}

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be impossible. I googled around and i could't fine anything. I do use coda too.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around and reading up on some of the plugins like Lively ( separate preview window ). It appears to be a limitation of the API when it comes to previewing a different page from the one you are editing. Which is a shame as I would dearly love to do the same thing you are requesting.